# Find mismatch (Keys and values) between two dicts in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Find mismatch (Keys and values) between two dicts

```
superset = {"a":1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d":4}
subset = {"a":1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d":4}
print(all(item in superset.items() for item in subset.items()))
# Expected output: True and desired output True


superset = {"a":1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d":4, "e": 5}
subset = {"a":1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d":5}
print(all(item in superset.items() for item in subset.items()))
# Expected output: False and desired output False
```

Below test Case, as i am checking only mismatch keys and values between two dicts, so extra keys and values will be ignored in either superset or subset dicts. In Below case in subset contains "e" is key for 5 is the corresponding value, same key or value does not present in superset so we can ignore because it is not mismatchin.

```
superset = {"a":1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d":4}
subset = {"a":1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d":4, "e": 5}
print(all(item in superset.items() for item in subset.items()))
# Expected output: True and desired output False
```

Comment: What difference do you make between "Expected output" and "Desired output"?

Comment: Below test Case, as i am checking only mismatch keys and values between two dicts, so extra keys and values will be ignored in either superset or subset dicts. In Below case in subset contains "e" is key for 5 is the corresponding value, same key or value does not present in superset so we can ignore because it is not mismatchin.

superset = {"a":1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d":4}
subset = {"a":1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d":4, "e": 5}
print(all(item in superset.items() for item in subset.items()))
# Expected output: True and desired output False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore mismatching keys, just check keys that exists in both dicts:

```
superset = {"a":1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d":4, "f":8}
subset = {"a":1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d":4, "e": 5}
print(
    all(
        superset[key] == subset[key] 
        for key in set(superset.keys()) & set(subset.keys())
    )
)
```

will print:

`True`

---

If you want to check that each dict contains no mismatched values from another, you should modify your code like this:

```
superset = {"a":1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d":4, "f": 10, "g": 5}
subset = {"a":1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d":4, "e": 5}
print(
    all(
        superset[key] == subset[key] 
        for key in set(superset.keys()) & set(subset.keys())
    ) and
    all(
        superset[key] not in subset.values()
        for key in set(superset.keys()) - set(subset.keys())
    ) and
    all(
        subset[key] not in superset.values()
        for key in set(subset.keys()) - set(superset.keys())
    )
)
```

will print:

`False`

Comment: superset = {"a":1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d":4, "f": 10, "g": 5}
subset = {"a":1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d":4, "e": 5} #output True: expected output False, reason, reason superset g key 5 and subset e key contain 5 and hence it is mismatch

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop once instead of loop several times like the accepted answer. Just ignore the keys that are not within the superset and since we are iterating with the subset it will automatically ignore all keys in the superset that are not in the subset.

```
print(all(subset[key] == superset[key] for key in subset if key in superset))
```

**Output:**

```
True
False
True
```